# How do you stop an iPhone timer without touching it?

Tags: iphone, siri, clock

I locked my iPhone X in a clear, timed safe such as kSafe to prevent myself from being distracted by the phone. I thought it would be convenient to use Siri and the iOS clock app to start a tea timer with the phone, but when the timer went off I was left with the endless jingle and vibration in the background with no way to stop it. I could get it to quiet a little by using FaceID. I've tried using Siri, but saying "hey Siri" does not seem to work.

Is there any way to stop a timer without touching a phone? Or am I trapped in my quarantined room with this jingle until the safe opens? I realize this is not a huge deal but it would be nice to know.

Comment: Can you use Hey Siri to do any functions?  Is the feature turned on in Settings? What version of iOS are you using?

Comment: @fsb I cannot use Hey Siri to do any functions while the timer is going. The feature is enabled and works normally when I am using the phone without a timer. I am on 13.3.1

Comment: This sounds so like putting the alarm clock at the end of the bed to make sure you get up...